# Counting repetition in r

Tags: r, count, repeat

I want to count the number of specific repetitions in my `dataframe`. Here is a reproducible example

```
df <- data.frame(Date= c('5/5', '5/5', '5/5', '5/6', '5/7'), 
                 First = c('a','b','c','a','c'),
                 Second = c('A','B','C','D','A'),
                 Third = c('q','w','e','w','q'),
                 Fourth = c('z','x','c','v','z'))
```

Give this:

```
  Date First Second Third Fourth
1  5/5     a      A     q      z
2  5/5     b      B     w      x
3  5/5     c      C     e      c
4  5/6     a      D     w      v
5  5/7     c      A     q      z
```

I read a big file that holds 400,000 instances and I want to know different statistics about specific attributes. For an example here I'd like to know how many times `a` happens on `5/5`. I tried using `sum(df$Date == '5/5' & df$First == 'a', na.rm=TRUE)` which gave me the right result here (2), but when I run it on the big data set, the numbers are not accurate.

Any idea why?

Comment: Can you check whether there are any leading/lagging spaces?  If that is the case `library(stringr); df[] <- lapply(df, str_trim)` and then try it.  Also `table(df[1:2])` would be more useful

Comment: @akrun I played with it a little bit and it worked out. Thank you!